# Using arara as a latex build tool with different output directory

Tags: pdftex, arara

I try to use `arara` as my LaTeX build tool, for the moment my LaTeX main header looks like the following

```
% arara: pdflatex : {options : "--output-directory=build"}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
```

I want to use a different build directory, which I tried to implement like above, but somehow this doesn't seem to work, I get the following error message in verbose mode

```
! I can't write on file `chapters/theorie.aux'.
\@include ...\immediate \openout \@partaux #1.aux 
                                              \immediate \write\@partau...
l.198 \include{chapters/theorie}
```

So I use a subfolder for my chapters which apparently creates some problems.
I would really like to know what is the correct way to do this?

Furthermore is there maybe the possibilty to speed the build process up ? 
Let's say I didn't commit any changes to my `.tex` files, in this case the build process should finish immediately.

Thank you

Comment: your build directory will need a chapters subdirectory I think (but I never redirect the output from tex it always causes problems and has no practical benefits really, you could just get arara to move the finished pdf).

Comment: Hello! `:)` I think `arara` is not the one to blame, but the `.aux` files dependencies. As David suggests, we could have a rule to move the resulting PDF to the desired location...

Comment: Let's say I don't use a build directory,  how can I speed up the build process? It's always the same even if I haven't commit any changes to my files.

Comment: @jrsm: Ah I see what you mean now. `:)` For the current version of `arara` (3.0), little can be done to speed up the build process. The new version has a feature for that, but it lacks a user manual, so it's not officially released yet. In the meantime, `latexmk` might help.